# Function for URL doesn't return correct value

Tags: jquery

I'm using 2 functions in my webshop to Auto set the `href` in my anchor tag

This is what they look like before the script :

```
<a class="Motifyer" data-query="Brand" data-value="@brand.Item1" href="#">
<a class="Motifyer" data-query="Brand" data-value="@brand.Item1" href="#">
```

And after the query :

```
<a class="Motifyer" data-query="Brand" data-value="@brand.Item1" href="http://localhost:44300/shop?Brand=Apple">
<a class="Motifyer" data-query="Brand" data-value="@brand.Item1" href="http://localhost:44300/shop?Brand=Samsung">
```

The smart think is (according to me) if the url contains `Brand=Samsung` the result would be:

```
<a class="Motifyer" data-query="Brand" data-value="@brand.Item1" href="http://localhost:44300/shop?Brand=Apple">
<a class="Motifyer" data-query="Brand" data-value="@brand.Item1" href="http://localhost:44300/shop">
<!-- Notice the removed query on the second one -->
```

---

The problem is that if I have multiple params in my query and if I remove the first `?xxx=xxx`, it sometimes dont change the first **&** into an **?**

Can someone tell me where the problem might be?

The following code contains my JS functions :

```
$('.Motifyer').each(function () {
    var url, query, value, queryCount, matches;

    url = window.location.href.replace("#", "");
    query = $(this).data('query');
    value = $(this).data('value');
    matches = url.match(/[a-z\d]+=[a-z\d]+/gi);
    queryCount = matches ? matches.length : 0;

    if (url.indexOf(query) > -1) {
        if (getParameterByName(query) == value) {
            url = url.replace("?" + query + "=" + value, "");
            url = url.replace("&" + query + "=" + value, "");
        } else {
            url = url.replace(query + "=" + getParameterByName(query), query + "=" + value)
        }

    } else {
        if (queryCount == 0) {
            url = url + "?" + query + "=" + value;
        } else {
            url = url + "&" + query + "=" + value;
        }
    }
    $(this).attr("href", url);
});

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine to me, this might work as a "quick" solution for your.

Insert this line: `url = url.replace("?" + query + "=" + value + "&", "?");`

```
if (url.indexOf(query) > -1) {
    if (getParameterByName(query) == value) {
        ----> Insert Right here <----
        url = url.replace("?" + query + "=" + value, "");
        url = url.replace("&" + query + "=" + value, "");
    } else {
        url = url.replace(query + "=" + getParameterByName(query), query + "=" + value)
    }

} else {
    if (queryCount == 0) {
        url = url + "?" + query + "=" + value;
    } else {
        url = url + "&" + query + "=" + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.